# Cursor goes to next line and indents by four spaces on hitting return in Xcode 7

Tags: macos, xcode7, auto-indent

Whenever I hit return the cursor goes to next line and indents by four spaces. How to rectify that?

Comment: How am I supposed to go to the next line then?

Comment: What is it you actually want to happen when you hit return?  Have you looked at the preferences?

Comment: preferenc is all good. What happens when u keep pressing enter/return in an editor? The cursor goes to the next line right? But it doesn't indent by four spaces on every new line right? That's whats happening here.